# Java: Getting installed text input languages on Windows

Tags: java

I was trying to figure out what are the input languages installed on Windows from a Java application. You can manually figure this from out Control Panel->Region and Language->Change keyboards(button)->General->Installed Services(bottom panel).

The background is that in the application I am forcing Locale.US using a following call -

```
 Component component = getAWTComponent();
 component.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(Locale.US)
```

But on some hosts US keyboard language is not installed (say a system in UK). I wanted to verify that the language is not available and throw an error or something.

Also, is it possible to install such services from Java (far-fetched may be..)?

Comment: Is getting the `default` locale useful to you? That of course can be done via java.

Comment: @vikingsteve Unfortunately no. Also (please correct me if I am wrong here) existence of a Locale in Java doesn't mean that the corresponding input services is installed on the system.

Comment: ok, does the same apply to `getAvailableLocales` (as per user2504380's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messing with the default keyboard layout is something that should only be done with great care. If you do this at all, you should give users an option to select which layout they want instead of forcing a certain layout on everyone.

Imagine your reaction if I wrote an app and tried to force you to use the German keyboard.

That said, the API will fall back to a valid keyboard layout when `Locale.US` isn't available. The code which does that is hidden in [sun.awt.im.InputContext.selectInputMethod()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/awt/im/InputContext.java#InputContext.selectInputMethod%28java.util.Locale%29)

Using reflection, you should be able to replicate the part of the code which checks whether some locale is supported.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. That looks promising. I would give it a try. And I do accept your concern about changing the Locale. But the application I am working is for internal purposes only and used for testing some other applications that we develop. So I can live with the risks - :)

Answer (score -1):

Java can found your default charset :

> ```
> public final static Charset CHARSET_SYSTEM =  
>           Charset.forName(System.getProperties().get("sun.jnu.encoding").toString());
> ```

then you can use it in a Scanner to transform input charset in UniCode :

```
Scanner scan = null;
final  void defineScan(Charset charsetCanBeNull) {
    scan = new Scanner(System.in, (null == charsetCanBeNull) 
           ? charset 
           : charsetCanBeNull);
}
```

Then you can use Scanner.methods(..)

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure I understand. It would return me a Charset being used. How would this help in what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I was talking about the first part of the question : `I was trying to figure out what are the input languages installed on Windows from a Java application.` this can help to find the keyboard used

Comment: "input languages" means "keyboard layouts". It's completely unrelated to locales (well, you can use a locale to look up a keyboard layout). But the locales which Java knows about have no relation to the installed keyboard layouts of the OS.

Answer (score -1):

```
    static public void main(String[]args) {
        Locale al[] = DateFormat.getAvailableLocales();
        for (Locale l : al) {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As mentioned to @vikingsteve this wouldn't useful. I think this returns a list of Locales that Java supports. Doesn't have to do anything with text input languages installed.